# Help regarding a text book question about a complex inequality

Tags: complex-analysis

I saw this exercise in a  textbook(Complex Analysis By Guillame):Prove that for any complex polynomial $$f(z)=\sum_0^n a_i z^k$$ ,the following holds :$$\int_{-1}^{1}(f(x))^2 \leq \pi \int_0^{2 \pi}|f(e^{\iota \theta })|^2 .$$ What  is the link to Parseval's identity here  I tried a lot but unfortunately could not prove it . The same quesion asks in the next part 
.
Establish the following variant of Hilbert's inequality, that
$$
\left|\sum_{j, k=0}^n \frac{a_j a_k}{j+k+1}\right| \leq \pi \sum_{k=0}^n\left|a_k\right|^2
$$
with strict inequality unless the complex numbers $c_0, \ldots, c_n$ are all zero.
i would be highly obliged for any help\hints \suggestions

Comment: Check this https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3703129/42969 – found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cint_%7B-1%7D%5E%7B1%7D(f(x))%5E2%20%5Cleq%20%5Cpi%20%5Cint_0%5E%7B2%20%5Cpi%7D%7Cf(e%5E%7B%5Ciota%20%5Ctheta%20%7D)%7C%5E2%20.%24)

Comment: @Martin R,thanks for the link and million thanks for the math search tool!I had been looking for a tool like this for  a long time

Comment: More information here: [How to search with Approach0](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/29267/42969)

Comment: Can we close this as a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3703129/42969?

Comment: Your added question is asked here https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2730121/42969 (again found with Approach0). – It is generally a bad idea to ask multiple questions in one post.

Comment: Actually in the book where I saw it,the 'two 'are a single question.Anyways,thank you once more for the link